# How allocator can solve fragmentation?

Tags: heap-memory, allocator, fragmentation

I am writing a project "Threadsafe allocator". Every thread has its own heap, and heap consists of blocks(4 KB). Allocator uses the memory from different blocks. What should I do to avoid fragmetation of data in blocks?

Answer (score 0):

A good start may be to read the ["jemalloc" paper](https://people.freebsd.org/~jasone/jemalloc/bsdcan2006/jemalloc.pdf).

Basically there's no easy answer to "How to avoid fragmentation". There are a lot of academic papers written on the subject. Read some and it might give you some insight into the problem and possible solutions.